# Reset part to original position in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a ball and an anchored wall. If i push the ball to the wall and the ball connects with the wall, the ball will reset back to its original position. Below is the script i have for the ball.

```
local ball = script.Parent
local wall = workspace.Wall

function reset(part)
    ball.Position = Vector3.new(124.5, 1.5, 133.5)
end

wall.Touched:Connect(reset)
```

However when the ball resets back to its original position, the ball continues to move in the direction that was pushed earlier. How do i make the ball stop exactly in the original position, and only move when the user pushes it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it's linear and angular velocities to a zero vector.

```lua
local ball = script.Parent
local wall = workspace.Wall

function reset(part)
    ball.Position = Vector3.new(124.5, 1.5, 133.5)
    ball.AssemblyLinearVelocity = Vector3.zero
    ball.AssemblyAngularVelocity = Vector3.zero
end

wall.Touched:Connect(reset)
```

You may also want to check if a part which touched the wall is a ball and nothing else.

```lua
local ball = script.Parent
local wall = workspace.Wall

function reset(part)
    if part == ball then
        ball.Position = Vector3.new(124.5, 1.5, 133.5)
        ball.AssemblyLinearVelocity = Vector3.zero
        ball.AssemblyAngularVelocity = Vector3.zero
    end
end

wall.Touched:Connect(reset)
```